# Login does not work

Tags: php, authentication, foreach

I have been trying to figure this out. It is quite easy but I just cant find the mistake. It looks like the mistake is in foreach, because everything above that works. When I fill the inputs and click the Login button, the script wont work.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) AND (!empty($_POST['username']) AND (!empty($_POST['password'])))) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $pass = hash('sha256',$password);

    $select = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= :username AND password= :password");
    $select->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $select->bindParam(':password', $pass);
    $select->execute();

    foreach ($select as $data) {
        if ($data['username'] == $username AND $data['password'] == $pass) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
            ?>
            <div class="echos">
                    <?php
                    echo "Login completed" . "<br>";
                    echo "<a href='http://jezecek.nostools.cz/'>Homepage</a>";
        }
        else {
            echo "Wrong username or password!" . "<br>";
            echo "<a href='http://jezecek.nostools.cz/include/registration.php'>Try again</a>";
        }       
    }   
}
else {
    echo "Fill all fields!" . "<br>";
    echo "<a href='http://jezecek.nostools.cz/include/login.php'>Try again</a>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Even if I use fetchAll() like this, it still doesnt work

```
$select = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= :username AND password= :password");
    $select->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $select->bindParam(':password', $pass);
    $select->execute();
    $result = $select->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $data) {
        if ($data['username'] == $username AND $data['password'] == $pass) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
            ?>
            <div class="echos">
                    <?php
                    echo "Login completed" . "<br>";
                    echo "<a href='http://jezecek.nostools.cz/'>Homepage</a>";
        }
```

Comment: first of all: use `password_hash()` to *safely* hash your passwords. just calling sha256 once is **not** secure.

Comment: forget to fetch data after `execute()`. Read http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: You need to add error handling to your database calls, for example by having PDO throw exceptions. Note that your logic is wrong: As you select on both the username and password, the only rows you'll find always match these conditions. Wrong username / password occurs when no rows are found in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please fetch data before going to loop

```
$select->execute();
$data=$select->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetch all of the rows in the result set :-

```
$result = $select->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error happens in the foreach because you are not fetching any data from your query. You might want to fetch data and loop through

```
$select->execute();
$data = $select->fetchAll();

foreach($data as $val) {
    //.....
```

Comment: That is not correct, you can loop over a PDO statement as it implements Traversable.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need loop either, just try this:

```
$data  = $select -> fetch();
if($data)
{
    // do login
}
```